# Codeigniter manage ebs payment gateway return url

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, return, payment-gateway

Hi I am working on a ecommerce sites payment gateway part. I am not able to understand how to handle the return url from EBS payment gateway.

As like they mentioned in their documentation, the return url should be something like,

```
http://www.yourdomainname.com/response.extension?DR={DR}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you elaborate your question a bit more specific?

Comment: Once payment is successful, i need to get payment id/ order id from ebs server and need to save that in users tables for future references.